# Integration of a function containing $\Theta(x-x0)$ and $\Theta(x+x0)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate the following function (Planck radiation law) in the interval $\Lambda=\left[0,+\infty\right)$:
$$W(\lambda,T)=\frac{C_1}{\lambda^5\left(\exp\left(\frac{C_2}{\lambda T}\right)-1\right)}f(\lambda)$$
where:
$f(\lambda)=k\lambda\left[\Theta(\lambda+\lambda_0)-\Theta(\lambda-\lambda_0)\right]$
and $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function.
Using Maple, the result of the integral $$P=\int_0^{+\infty}W(\lambda,T)d\lambda$$ contains a limit. Is it possible to calculate the integral in a closed form ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you call a closed form.  The integral ends up being

$$C_1 k \int_0^{\lambda_0} \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^4 \left [\exp{\left (\frac{C_2}{\lambda T} \right)}-1 \right ]}$$

Sub $\lambda = 1/u$ and get

$$C_1 k \int_{u_0}^{\infty} du \, u^2 e^{-C_2 u/T} \left (1-e^{-C_2 u/T} \right )^{-1} $$

where $u_0 = 1/\lambda_0$.  You can Taylor expand the quantity in parentheses to get

$$C_1 k \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \int_{u_0}^{\infty} du \, u^2 e^{-(m+1)C_2 u/T}$$

The integral is very doable:

$$\int_{u_0}^{\infty} du \, u^2 e^{-(m+1)C_2 u/T} = \frac{d^2}{da^2} \int_{u_0}^{\infty} du \, e^{-a u} |_{a=(m+1) C_2/T} = \frac{(m+1)^2 (T/C_2)u_0^2+ 2 (m+1) (T/C_2)^2 u_0 + 2 (T/C_2)^3}{(m+1)^3} e^{-(m+1)C_2 u_0/T}$$

The sums of the above may then be expressed in terms of polylogarithms.

Comment: Are you sure of the result of the calculation? The integral seems not converge.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: how so?  The substitution should make clear that the integral does in fact converge.

Comment: The sum of the last expression from $m=0$ to $m=\infty$ doesn't converge. It's $\infty$ for $(T/C_2)u_0^2\neq 0$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: due to an omission on my part; thank you for drawing my attention to it.